# Change <body id="grid"> to <body class="list"> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I know how to change an id: `$("body").attr('id', 'list');`

But now I want to change the attribute itself; instead of `id='grid'` I want to have `class='list'`

For example, this:

```
<body id="grid">
```

Should turn to:

```
<body class="list">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really *change* the attribute using jQuery, but it is very easy to achieve what you want in two actions:

```
$("body").addClass('list').removeAttr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like:

```
$('body').removeAttr('id').attr('class', 'list');
```